# Binary file versioning on windows - linux systems

Tags: git, version-control, binary-data

In our project, we currently use git version control for our source code. However, we have a need to track our binary releases (virtual machines, configured setups) as well. They are usually some gigabytes each, which doesn't work well with git.

What's your suggestion on a good tool for this?

Our workstations are Windows-based, whereas our servers are Linux boxes. We use git in a central way, as in we have one server hosting and then take backups from that server.

Since we already have git, my initial idea (partly based on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git)) was to use [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) or [git fat](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat) for this as they would integrate with the workflow. However, it seems neither of them has very good Windows support (git-annex [has beta support](http://git-annex.branchable.com/todo/windows_support/), git fat [has only support in a branch a single user made](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat/issues/43)). That seems too immature for versioning of really important, production-quality stuff.

Non-git solutions can be offered as well.